# how can I return the first element of this array?

Tags: node.js, arrays, angular, typescript

The array blobstream looks like this:

```
blobstream = [1,2,3]
```

I only want to return by each loop one array
first loop: 1
second loop: 2
third loop: 3

What is the best solution to do that? Thanks Eden

```
 async function main() {
        let i = 1;
    
        for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
            const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name);
    
            const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
            const download = await blobToString(await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody);
            console.log(download);
            blobstream.push(download);
        }
        return blobstream;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for an [*async generator function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) (like `containerClient.listBlobsFlat()`, which also appears to be an async generator function). That would look something like this:

```
async function* main() {
//            ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− generator function
    for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
        const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name);

        const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
        const download = await blobToString(await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody);
        console.log(download);
        yield download;
//      ^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− yield a result
    }
}
```

Async generator functions return async generators, which you can use in `for-await-of` loops (or directly):

```
for await (const value of main()) {
    // Here, `value` will be each value yielded by the generator
}
```

Here's an example using `setTimeout` to emulate the asynchronous part:

```js
const delay = (ms, value) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, value));

async function somethingAsync(value) {
    await delay(Math.random() * 1000 + 200);
    return value * 2;
}

async function* main() {
    for (const value of [1, 2, 3, 4]) {
        const x = await somethingAsync(value);
        yield x;
    }
}

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log("Start");
        for await (const x of main()) {
            console.log(x);
        }
        console.log("End");
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.message || String(e));
    }
})();
```